# UITextView inside UIScrollView is not First Responder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder

I have a UITextView on a View that becomes the first responder.

When I embed the UITextView inside of a UIScrollView in Interface Builder the UITextView is no longer the first responder. I am not sure what has changed?

**I would like the UITextView to become the first responder.**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(540,620)];
    composeTextView.delegate = self;    
    [composeTextView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Untitled1ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    UITextField *composeTextView;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *composeTextView;

@end
```

this is my .m file:

```
#import "Untitled1ViewController.h"

@implementation Untitled1ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize composeTextView;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(540,620)];
    composeTextView.delegate = self;    
    [composeTextView becomeFirstResponder];


}
```

in IB, i've connected the following:
textField to composeTextView
scrollView to scrollView
and the textField delegate to the file's owner.

Try again and advise.

Comment: Still no luck for me. Is your composeTextView inside of your scrollView?

Comment: Also I'm using a UITextView and not a UITextField

Comment: Thanks! This code works great. I realized my UITextView was not hooked up in IB. Small mistake, causing huge headaches.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same, added some code and it works OK:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(540,620);
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
[composeTextView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I added your code, and still no luck. Could it be IB? I have a UIView that contains a UIScrollView. Inside of that is a UITextView and some UIButtons. All controls are connected in IB.

Comment: Hey, I've done everything again, and from Scratch, i'll attach it as a new answer so i could mark the Code.

Answer (score 0):

The text view takes scroll events and hence the scroll events are not passed on further in its responder chain. If you are not interested in scrolling the text view, disable the scrolling in textView (use nib or scrollEnabled property), now, scrollView will start taking scroll events.

Comment: Even if I disable scrolling for the textview, it does not become the first responder

Comment: It does, I have verified. I am quite sure about this. If you disable scrolling in the textView, then the container - scrollView will start taking the events.

Comment: I have modified my code to composeTextView.scrollEnabled = NO; and [scrollView becomesFirstResponder]; I have also tried the former code and [composeTextView becomesFirstResponder] with no luck.

Comment: Ok I mistook your question, call -becomeFirstResponder on the textView should work. Probably you have missed the outlet connections. put a breakpoint in your -viewDidLoad method and see if the compositTextView / scrollView are nil.

Comment: My outlets were not setup for the textView in IB. Thanks!

Comment: As soon as you name an ivar as IBOutlet in interface file, put an assert statement in either -awakeFromNib or in -viewDidLoad method like: NSAssert (nil!=outletInstance, @"outletInstance is nil") so that the application traps any nil conditions for outlets. This is a good way to identify if outlets are nil.